# How to load something in the background on blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, background

My app load some data from server and show it on the display. When app closed I want to check storage on the device and if not all data hadn't been loaded yet by user, then load data from server to device. Let me clarify I want do it when application not worked.

I read about background processes, but don't understand how it works and how to implement my feature via them. Can you describe how it should work in balckberry? All help would be appreciated

Comment: You can make a proxy application by extending `Application` class for performing background task. From the API documentation, `Applications which do not require any user interaction may be derived directly from this class. Applications which require user interaction should be derived from UiApplication`. Link here, http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the app to run in the background then you can override the onClose method in your main screen.

```
public boolean onClose() {
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().requestBackground();
    return true;
}
```